# Prototype function with my while loop condition error in C

Tags: c, while-loop

How could I run my own prototype function with my while loop condition?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

msghere(char *text){
    printf("%s",text);
    return 0;
}
void main(){
    char inp[256]={0};
    clrscr();
    while( strcmp(inp,"pass") && msghere("Error!")){
        memset(inp,0,strlen(inp));
        printf("Type \"pass\": ");
        gets(inp);
    }
    msghere("Right Answer!");
    getch();
}
```

This code prints an output of:

```
Error!Right Answer!
```

Comment: 1) Don't use `gets`, use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. 2) Declare `msghere` with a return type (`int` in your case). 3) To avoid these mistakes in the future: compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` for GCC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a do-while loop and something like an if condition.

```
int msghere(char *text){
    printf("%s",text);
    return 1;
}
int main(void)
{    
    do
    {
    //your code
    }while( (strcmp(inp, "pass") == 0 ? 0 : msghere("error!")) );
}
```

**Why the do-while?**
Because you want your user to make an input before you check it the first time. Logical right?

**WTF is "**`while( (strcmp(inp, "pass") == 0 ? 0 : msghere("error!")) )`**"?**
First of all: bad coding style. It is a short version if/else. if the first condition is true return the value after the ? otherwise return the value after :

**Why return 1; in msghere()?**
Because your do while loop will evaluate if there was an error. Error == True -> do it again.

**What you should do:** 
is something like the following:

```
// your original msghere
int main(void)
{
  int passed = 0;  //false
  // some code
  while(!passed) //while not passed
  {
    //read input with fgets like said in the comments
    if(strcmp(inp, "pass") == 0)
    {
       passed = 1; // true
    }
    else
    {
      msghere("error");
    }
  }
}
```

it uses a status variable and is much more easyier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int msghere(const char *text)
{
    printf("%s",text);
    return 1; /* you want 1 instead of 0, because (strcmp != 0) && 1 == true */
}

int main(void)
{
    char inp[256];

    clrscr();
    do {
        printf("Type \"pass\": ");
        fgets(inp, sizeof inp, stdin); /* gets is deprecated, use fgets */
    } while (strcmp(inp, "pass\n") && msghere("Error!"));
    msghere("Right Answer!");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

*Why is there `\n` after pass in `while((strcmp(inp, "pass\n") && msghere("Error!"))`*

Because `fgets` puts an extra `\n` at the end of the string, you can skip this new line using:

```
if (fgets(inp, sizeof inp, stdin) != 0)
{
    size_t len = strlen(inp);

    if (len > 0 && inp[len - 1] == '\n')
        inp[len - 1] = '\0';
    /* ... */
}
```

Seems that you are using Turbo C or an old compiler, use a modern compiler (eg. MinGW), furthermore:

- There is no need to initialize `inp`
- There is no need to `memset` on each iteration
- Functions must return some type (in this case `int`) or `void`
- The `const` qualifier explicitly declares a data object as something that cannot be changed, use it in order to help the compiler build better code.
- Use `int main(void)` instead of  `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

The strcmp() function return's an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if string1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found,respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than string2.

Therefore your call to **strcmp** in while loop retuns non-zero value.so, 
the next condition is evaluated i.e., calling the **function(msghere)**. The function executes, prints the result and returns zero, which makes the condition to be false in while loop.

Now, you know what to do.